# jQuery: Sortable nested but not continuous

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm developing the page locally, so unfortunately I can't show an example, but I have two "lists" build of of jQuery mobile.

I want both lists to be sortable using the jquery ui plugin.

it might look something like this:

```
<div class="sortable"> //1st sortable wrapper
  <div> //list item for 1st sortable wrapper
    <div>
     <div>
       <div class="sortable"> //2nd sortable list wrapper
         <div> //list item for 2nd sortable wrapper
```

Then I'm calling

```
jQuery(".sortable").sortable()
```

So I basically have two independent sortables.  One set of sortables inside the 1st set of sortables.  Each grouping should be independent of the other set of sortables.

It might be worth nothing that the second set of sortables are added dynamically to the page.

After adding, I am calling

```
jQuery(".sortable").sortable('refresh')
```

To no avail, the second set of sortables that are added dynamically are never sortable.  When I try and drag them, the parent .sortable drags instead.

All the plugins I see assume that the elements are one right after the next.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

In the jQuery-ui-sortable file development version.

There is a line that accounts for this:

change:

```
if(itemElement != this.currentItem[0] //cannot intersect with itself
            &&  this.placeholder[intersection == 1 ? "next" : "prev"]()[0] != itemElement //no useless actions that have been done before
            &&  !$.ui.contains(this.placeholder[0], itemElement) //no action if the item moved is the parent of the item checked
            && (this.options.type == 'semi-dynamic' ? !$.ui.contains(this.element[0], itemElement) : true)
            //&& itemElement.parentNode == this.placeholder[0].parentNode // only rearrange items within the same container
        )
```

to:

```
if(itemElement != this.currentItem[0] //cannot intersect with itself
            &&  this.placeholder[intersection == 1 ? "next" : "prev"]()[0] != itemElement //no useless actions that have been done before
            &&  !$.ui.contains(this.placeholder[0], itemElement) //no action if the item moved is the parent of the item checked
            && (this.options.type == 'semi-dynamic' ? !$.ui.contains(this.element[0], itemElement) : true)
            && itemElement.parentNode == this.placeholder[0].parentNode // only rearrange items within the same container
        )
```

Bascially, remove the comment on the last line.